# RegEx to get the pattern for a output string in shell script

Tags: regex, grep

I run the command `grep` to get certain output and store it into a variable. The output of grep command is:

```
5.3.1-6.2011171513.ASMOS6
```

but I need to only parse out `5.3.1-6` and store that version in a variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
TEXT=5.3.1-6.2011171513.ASMOS6
RES=$(echo $TEXT | cut -d. -f-3)
```

We `cut` the string on `.` and then get the first 3 pieces.

With **awk**

```
RES=$(echo $TEXT | awk -F. 'OFS=FS {print $1,$2,$3}')
```

`OFS=FS` meaning we get the delimiter to print that was defined with `-F`.

Comment: Awesome !! Both of them work great. Thank You!
I was using regex (\\d)(\\.)(\\d)(\\.)(\\d)(-)(\\d)

Comment: Good to read it worked for you, @JumpOffBox! Sometimes either `cut` or `awk` are easier to handle and understand. If you are done, you can mark the question as answered. Cheers!

Comment: Could you also suggest why I was going wrong with above reg ex?

Comment: Please indicate the exact command you were using. Were you using `sed` with `regex (\\d)...`?

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, I was looking to use same awk and cut to parse version e.g in string
res3=asmos-no-5.3.1-6.2011171513.ASMOS6, 
but delimiter either gives me 
5.3.1 or 1-6 but not complete "5.3.1-6", hence I used reg ex
$(echo $res3| sed -e 's/.*[0-9]\.[0.9]\.[0-9]\-[0-9].*/g')
which was not working even cut or awk was not working to get 5.3.1-6 in above res3 string>
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As you tag says linux, I'll assume that you have a modern grep that supports the `-o` option.

You can do

```
var=$(grep -o 'regex' file)
```

To capture just the regex to a variable.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the problem you're having getting just `5.3.1-6`, you have to edit your question to **show us the regex youare currently using**.

IHTH

Comment: The above said sting is the output I get and store it in a variable.
$var = 5.3.1-6.2011171513.ASMOS6
I need stored in another variable $var2, only 5.3.1-6 from string($var) and do not need rest of the characters in the string.
The issue is the version can change this time it is 5.3.1-6, next time it could be 7.4.5-2

Comment: The above said sting is the output I get and store it in a variable.
$var = 5.3.1-6.2011171513.ASMOS6
I need stored in another variable $var2, only 5.3.1-6 from string($var) and do not need rest of the characters in the string.
The issue is the version can change this time it is 5.3.1-6, next time it could be 7.4.5-2
I use reg ex (\\d)(\\.)(\\d)(\\.)(\\d)(-)(\\d)